# How can i use ‚momentjs‘ in a ‚binary-parser‘ formatter?

Tags: node.js, parsing, binary, node-modules

Can anybody help me please. How can i use moment in a formatter?

i think this is not a problem from node or binary parser. it is my understanding i think.

```
const Parser = require("binary-parser").Parser;
const moment = require('moment');

let time = function(timestamp) {
  return moment(timestamp, 'YYMMDDHHmmssSS').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS');
};

let Telegram = new Parser()
  .string('timestamp', {encoding: 'hex', length: 7, formatter: time});
```

The Exception is:

```
evalmachine.:9
return moment(timestamp, 'YYMMDDHHmmssSS').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS');
                                                                 ^

ReferenceError: moment is not defined
at Parser. (evalmachine.:9:2)
...
```

I think the Problem is that Parser don't know moment. But how can i realize that?
i have tried to import moment directly in the binary-parser module. But it doesn't working.

If i run moment outside of Parser then it is working.

Maybe anybody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `formatter` function runs without the `momentjs` context. I am guessing because of the way it consumes the `formatter` property. In the code found [here](https://github.com/keichi/binary-parser/blob/c9817403725364303023cb7baff15d91dc866d41/lib/binary_parser.js#L412), the code is:

```
if (this.code.formatter) {
    ... (ctx, varName, this.options.formatter)
```

Because of the [funny](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/) way the `this` keyword works, it's bound to the object (`options`) and because that declaration does not contain `momentjs`, it says that it is not defined.

You can get a better understanding of this by looking at line `735`:

```
ctx.pushCode("{0} = ({1}).call(this, {0});", varName, formatter);
```

It's bound to the current object.

---

P.S.: I copied the code and pasted it on Node.js and it's working perfectly. ^That is a possible explanation.

Comment: ahh, okay. I think I understand. The only way to format the timestamp is to do it after the parser creates the output right? Or did u have an another idea?